# How to properly use Scopes, Groups, and Users using Gravitee to determine user access in portals and APIs

Tags: gravitee

I have reviewed the [Gravitee 4.0 AM Documentation](https://documentation.gravitee.io/am/guides/administration) and am having trouble connecting how to configure users, groups, roles, and permissions so that the OAuth token would include a user's roles for my custom application in their token.

My goal is to have the values structured something like the following:

### User

| Username | Group |
| --- | --- |
| Admin01 | appNameAdmins |
| User01 | appNameUsers |
| User02 | appNameUsers |

### Group

| Group Name | Permissions |
| --- | --- |
| appNameAdmins | module01[create, read, list, update, delete] |
| appNameUsers | module01[read, list] |

So when a user authenticates using the OAuth2 API, their `access_token` would look something like the following

```json
{
  "sub": "12345ab1-ab12-1234-a12b-a1bc12345678",
  "aud": "12345ab1-ab12-1234-a12b-a1bc12345678",
  "domain": "12345ab1-ab12-1234-a12b-a1bc12345678",
  "scope": "openid roles full_profile",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8092/ecs2-local/oidc",
  "exp": 1693962272,
  "iat": 1693955072,
  "user": {
    "id": "12345ab1-ab12-1234-a12b-a1bc12345678",
    "createdAt": "Mon Aug 28 23:26:10 GMT 2023",
    "updatedAt": "Tue Sep 05 23:04:32 GMT 2023",
    "source": "default-idp-12345ab1-ab12-1234-a12b-a1bc12345678",
    "username": "Admin01",
    "displayName": "Sample Admin",
    "email": "admin@email.com",
    "groups": [
      "appNameAdmins"
    ],
    "permissions": [
      "module01.create",
      "module01.list",
      "module01.read",
      "module01.update",
      "module01.delete",
    ]
  },
  "jti": "SAMPLE_JTI"
}
```